# Как ставить метку в leaflet при нажатии ЛКМ?

Tags: javascript, html, css, leafletjs

Относительно недавно познакомился с leaflet и сделал свою карту. Мне хочется, чтобы при нажатии ЛКМ по карте, на самой карте появлялась метка. Но главное, чтобы эту метку могли видеть другие пользователи, а не только я. Как это сделать? Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо повесить обработчик на клацанье ЛКМ который будет считывать координаты на карте (Долгота + широта), потом передавать AJAX эти координаты в базу данных (если вы админ вашего сайта), потом отдавать пользователям которые имеют другой статус эти метки с базы данных. Не очень уверен что данная библиотека вам чем-то поможет в решении поставленной задачи, по сути она просто обертка над Google maps API...